# issue in function calling in Ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two function first in one calls & other in another class.I have the first function defined in other class.I am calling that function in other class.I have my second function defined in its own class.

**FirstClass.m** has **FirstFunction** function & i am calling it in **SecondClass.m**.

SecondClass.m has **SecondFuncion** function & i am calling it in **SecondClass.m**.First function fetch data from server using AFnetworking & give response. As of now i am calling functions like this in **SecondClass.m**

```
 SecondClass *sec = [[SecondClass alloc]init];
                [sec FirstFunction];
                [self SecondFunction];
```

I want  to call second function when working of first s completed.But here first function is asynchronous so second function does not wait for the response of first function.Please tell how can i do this?Can i use some kind of listener so code should not proceed ahead it should wait for response for the first function.

Comment: can't understand your question. please elaborate perfectly.

Comment: Please use completion block for it

Answer (score 0):

------Define your own completion block.

```
typedef void(^myCompletion)(BOOL);
```

------Create a method which takes your completion block as a parameter.

```
-(void) myMethod:(myCompletion) compblock
{
    //do stuff
    compblock(YES);
}
```

-----This is how you use it.

```
[self myMethod:^(BOOL finished) 
{
    if(finished)
    {
        NSLog(@"Function execute successfully");
        //Call your second Method Here
    }
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set an observer in `[sec FirstFunction]` such that as the work of `firstFunction` completes it calls `[self SecondFunction]`

In [sec FirstFunction] you write this method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationName" object:self];
```

and in your current viewController you use this observer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(somethingHappens:) name:@"notificationName" object:nil];

-(void)somethingHappens:(NSNotification*)notification
{
            [self SecondFunction];
}
```

Comment: What is notification name here and also obj?

Comment: in place of obj you can write self, and @"notificationName" is just a name given to the observer you can write any name over there, but just make sure that in both places the name should be same

Comment: feels like you try to hammer a nail with a bulldozer.